# How can i make a layout that can be used for all choice i had

Tags: android

I tried to create an expert system using eclipse.
In the expert system that I created, the user does not input the answer "yes" or "not".
But a more-Specific answers.
The concept layout that I use as a quiz.
Any answer will lead to the next layout.
The difference is the number of choices for each question has a different answer.
I have 10 questions.

Example:
1.  The first question has answer options  3 (a, b and c)
2.  The Second question has answer options 2 (a and b )
3.  The Third question has answer option   4 (a,b,c and d)

What confuses me is the making of layouts.
So far I think to make a layout for any questions I had, because as I said earlier, each question has a number of different answers.

I want to ask is whether the 10 layouts that I created earlier can be replaced by only 1 layout?
1 layout which can be used for all the questions I had.

I hope you understood what I want to ask you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list that holds each questions answers. this way you can create a ListView that will hold your answers.
this should be a simple way to have one layout.
a simple ListView tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html